# Is crossdomain.xml exclusive to Adobe?

Tags: nginx, cross-domain, minio

We use MinIO as our storage server. The issue is that the objects are accessible to the public Internet. To solve this issue someone suggested to use `crossdomain.xml` file to restrict access to resources if the request is initiated from our domain only. However from what I read everywhere, it looks like that file is exclusive to Adobe products.

Is that correct? And if yes, what is the alternative solution?

Our webserver is nginx.

Comment: Have you consider set firewall on host OS of MinIO?

Comment: I have already tried that. First ```ufw default deny incoming``` and then ```ufw allow from 1111.2222.3333.4444 to any port 443``` and it didn't work and interrupted the communication between webserver and storage server.

Comment: If the entire communication is done (from internet) via web server add in `nginx`  IP filtering like here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/

Comment: We are behind Cloudflare proxy.